# Read more for a InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

could you help me?
I have a jQuery function that show more or less text and the button, according the size choice.
The problem is that I don't know what to pass from the InnerHTMl. Here is the example. I tried with de `TEXTT` variable, but this doesn't works. For examples if I pass a text from the HTML this works.

```js
function write(y) {
  var textt = (document.getElementById(y).innerHTML += document.querySelector( "#"+ y +" textarea" ).value);
  $.fn.gotof(textt);
}

$.fn.gotof = function(pe){

  var minimized_elements = $(pe);

  minimized_elements.each(function(){    
    var t = $(this).text();        
    if(t.length < 10) return;

    $(this).html(
      t.slice(0,10)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
      '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(10,t.length)+' <a href="#" class="less">Less</a></span>'
    );
  }); 

  $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide().prev().hide();
    $(this).next().show();        
  });

  $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
  });
};
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant HTML ?

Comment: Read more about [how to create a jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).